# Cannot fire "loadVideoByUrl('...')" of Youtube's Iframe-API – undefined

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

it seems that I am missing something obvious here but I can not get

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player1');
    // here everything is fine and I can see the 
    // function as part of player
    console.log(player);
    // but here it says "player.loadVideoByUrl()" undefined
    player.loadVideoByUrl("https://youtu.be/bHQqvYy5KYo");
    player.playVideo();
}
```

to work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May I ask, why don't you add iframe_api as a static script in page? Is it the way Youtube provides?

Comment: It is part of the youtube official documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference Never thought about it any further until now.

Comment: I see, it's irrelevant to our case, I added an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `player` is not initialized while you're calling the `loadVideoByUrl` function. In documentation, they use

```
events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
```

events of player. It seems player object constructs asynchronously. So if you use those events, code becomes like below:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player1', {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(){
     player.loadVideoByUrl("https://youtu.be/bHQqvYy5KYo");
     player.playVideo();
}
```